# Mongodb findAndModify query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
    db.collection("mycollec").findOneAndUpdate(
        { "ID": "12345"},
      { $setOnInsert: {
                "ID": "12345",
                "Previous_Address": null,
                "Current_Address": null},
        }
        $set: {"temp": "7th Street"}
        $rename: {"Current_Address": "Previous_Address"},
        $rename: {"temp": "Current_Address"},
        $set: {"Date": new Date(), "Valid": true}
      },
    {
        returnNewDocument: true,  
        upsert: true 
        }, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        //db.close();
    });
```

problem with this code is that it always returns null..

explanation of code:
if you cannot find the id given, insert a document and shift the user's current address to his previous address...and update his current address to wtv the user gave you which in this case is the value in "temp"

However, if you can find the user, then just shift his current address to his previous address

can anyone help with this

just edited it accordingly, it still returns null :c

Comment: You really should be using [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) with modern drivers, and it's `returnOriginal: false` as well as different syntax of the arguments.

Comment: Which by the way is your main problem here because [`.findAndModify()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#findAndModify) also has "positional" arguments for "query" and "update" and not the "named keys" you are using here. That is the syntax for the ["shell method"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/), and not the node driver

Comment: Also don't "open" and "close" connections on calls. That's just in the documentation demonstrations as "self contained tests". Real applications keep the connection open for the lifecycle of the application.

Comment: hello i just edited my question taking into account ur comments.. my query still returns null... is the logic within the update itself where the issue lies?

Comment: It's **`returnOriginal: false`** and not the invalid option you actually used.

Comment: Thank you for your input! The query now works but  "Previous_Address" and "Current_Address" are always null.. I still believe the issue might be with the update itself; however i still cant quite figure out what it is